# My models are not showing in Django Admin after OTP Token implementation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, totp

I wanted to secure my Django Admin so I followed the steps in [here](https://www.cloudwithdjango.com/multi-factor-authentication-mfa-for-your-django-admin-page/) and I implemented django-otp to the my website. The token works fine. I can login my admin page safely but my models doesn't show up in my admin page.

For example: Before the OTP Implementation I was able to post a new blog or something but now I cant at all. There are nothing about blogs in my admin.

I am logging as a superuser and I tried to create another superuser and logging but it didn't change.

I think this error might be caused by the admin.py file configurations, but I'm not sure.

Here is my `urls.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns # new
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_otp.admin import OTPAdminSite
from django_otp.plugins.otp_totp.models import TOTPDevice
from django_otp.plugins.otp_totp.admin import TOTPDeviceAdmin

class OTPAdmin(OTPAdminSite):
   pass

admin_site = OTPAdmin(name='OTPAdmin')
admin_site.register(User)
admin_site.register(TOTPDevice, TOTPDeviceAdmin)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin_site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('', include('portfolio.urls')),
    path('', include('services.urls')),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),

]
```

Here is an example of my `admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import BlogPost

@admin.register(BlogPost)
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('blogname', 'related_service', 'available', 'created_at' )
    list_filter = ('available', 'related_service',)
    search_fields = ('blogname',)
    prepopulated_fields = {
        'slug':('blogname',)
    }
```

Comment: Note: In my opinion the best answer on the duplicate target is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612400/auto-register-django-auth-models-using-custom-admin-site/75631883#75631883)